# Distinguishing between active vs passive perception

Tags: perception

there's a well-known diagram made proposed by Fant (see image, passive perception is ABCDE and passive perception is ABCKFE) but it a quite anatomical and neurological account. (And I'm not even sure what the arrows represent, specifically arrow A!).

Are there generally-accepted alternatives to representing the difference between the two kinds of speech perception?
[image: passive perception be active perception]

Comment: Arrow A: we can hear with ears (a source of input).

Comment: You seem to presume that there actually exist two kinds of perception; my understanding is that these represent classes of theories about perception, not distinct objects. See this for an overview of classical models: http://clas.mq.edu.au/speech/perception/speechperception/classic_models.html